Entered wrong date in expected period of stay on Canadian visitor visa application
I am going for a summer school to Canada and the school runs from July 1 to July 26. I had to apply for a Canadian visitor visa for that purpose.
Now on the main application form I had to put the dates indicating the period for which I would stay in Canada. Accidentally I put the dates of June 1 to June 26.
However the true dates (i.e., July 1 to July 26) is echoed at several other places, including the letter of invitation and also the letter which promises a financial support and which I have uploaded as a document validating my financial stability.
What should I do in this situation? Also what are the odds that my visa application gets cancelled due to this?
Moreover, if it gets cancelled would it be an issue to apply for it again and get it approved?

What did IRCC say when you asked them?

If there's an option to contact them so next to your application in your account (where you can see the status of your application), use that. Otherwise use the form given by @Traveller

Thanks, I couldn't find any other options to contact, and used the form given by @Traveller ; thanks to both of you!

@AdityaGuhaRoy When you get a reply don’t forget to post an answer :-)

Sure @Traveller and thanks a lot.
